# Component Inheritance with vue js

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to build a base `DataComponent` which will contain the common functionality required for many other components which deal with basic CRUD entities.
So far I have

```js
//main.js
import Vue from 'vue';

new Vue({
  el:'#app',
  components:{
    DataComponent,
    Quotation
  }
});
```

```js
//data-component.js
import Vue from 'vue';

export
default Vue.extend({

      data() {
          return {
            saved: false
          }
        },

        methods: {

          //This method will be used by all inheriting components to alert
          //the user regarding any changes which need to be saved.
          
          alertSave(entity, fields, intFields) {
              var changeCount = 0;
              fields.forEach(function(field) {
                
                var compareWith = this[field];
                
                //Here "this" need to refer to the child instance but it does not
                //how can I achieve?
                
                if ((compareWith || entity[field.camelToSnake()]) &&
                  entity[field.camelToSnake()] !== compareWith) {
                  changeCount++;
                }
              });
              intFields.forEach(function(field) {
                var compareWith = parseInt(this[field]);
                if ((compareWith || entity[field.camelToSnake()]) &&
                  entity[field.camelToSnake()] !== compareWith) {
                  changeCount++;
                }
              });
              vm.saved = changeCount <= 0;
            },
          
            //sanitizeValue method works as intended as it does not have any reference to "this"
          
            sanitizeValue(value) {
              if (value) {
                return String(value).trim();
              } else {
                return null;
              }
            },
          
            //In getDbData method also this needs to refer to the inheriting child instance
            //from where this method is called - how can I achieve it?
          
            getDbData(entity) {
              if (entity) {
                this.dbTextFields.forEach(function(field) {
                  this[field] = entity[field.camelToSnake()];
                });
                this.dbIntFields.forEach(function(field) {
                  this[field] = entity[field.camelToSnake()];
                });
                this.dbObjFields.forEach(function(field) {
                  this[field] = entity[field.camelToSnake()];
                });
                this.dbAppendedFields.forEach(function(field) {
                  this[field] = entity[field.camelToSnake()]
                });
                this.saved = true;

              }
            }
        });
```

```js
//quotation.js

import DataComponent from './data-component';

export default DataComponent.extend({
  
  data(){
    return{
      id:0,
      date:'',
      remarks:'',
      terms:'',
      quote:{},
      dbTextFields:['to', 'org', 'address', 'items', 'description', 'quoted_by'],
      dbIntFields:['quote_ref', 'quantity', 'amount', 'discount', 'total'],
      dbObjFields:['inquiry', 'booking']
    }
  },
  
  methods:{
    setDbData(){
      let entity = this.quote;
      this.getDbData(entity);
      
      //getDbData gives error as "this" in getDbData does not refer to this
      // child component and so this.dbTextFields becomes undefined.
      
    }
  }
  
});
```

```
How to achieve method inheritance as I am trying to do? Is it possible in Vue.js?
```

**Edit**

If I change the signature of the method in data-component.js as under, passing the instance of inheriting component ("this") as vm , it works

```js
//data-component.js
import Vue from 'vue';

export
default Vue.extend({

      data() {
          return {
            saved: false
          }
        },

        methods: {

          //This method will be used by all inheriting components to alert
          //the user regarding any changes which need to be saved.
          
          alertSave(entity, fields, intFields, vm) {
              var changeCount = 0;
              fields.forEach(function(field) {
                //var compareWith = this[field];
                var compareWith = vm[field];
                
                //Changed "this" to vm (passed as a parameter) 
                //how can I achieve?
                
                if ((compareWith || entity[field.camelToSnake()]) &&
                  entity[field.camelToSnake()] !== compareWith) {
                  changeCount++;
                }
              });
              intFields.forEach(function(field) {
                //var compareWith = parseInt(this[field]);
                var compareWith = parseInt(vm[field]);
                if ((compareWith || entity[field.camelToSnake()]) &&
                  entity[field.camelToSnake()] !== compareWith) {
                  changeCount++;
                }
              });
              vm.saved = changeCount <= 0;
            },
          
            //sanitizeValue method works as intended as it does not have any reference to "this"
          
            sanitizeValue(value) {
              if (value) {
                return String(value).trim();
              } else {
                return null;
              }
            },
          
            //In getDbData method also this needs to refer to the inheriting child instance
            //from where this method is called - how can I achieve it?
          
            getDbData(entity, vm) { //instance as "vm" parameter
            //change all this to vm
              if (entity) {
                vm.dbTextFields.forEach(function(field) {
                  vm[field] = entity[field.camelToSnake()];
                });
                vm.dbIntFields.forEach(function(field) {
                  vm[field] = entity[field.camelToSnake()];
                });
                vm.dbObjFields.forEach(function(field) {
                  vm[field] = entity[field.camelToSnake()];
                });
                vm.dbAppendedFields.forEach(function(field) {
                  vm[field] = entity[field.camelToSnake()]
                });
                vm.saved = true;

              }
            }
        });
```

And then in the inheriting component

```js
//quotation.js

import DataComponent from './data-component';

export default DataComponent.extend({
  
  data(){
    return{
      id:0,
      date:'',
      remarks:'',
      terms:'',
      quote:{},
      dbTextFields:['to', 'org', 'address', 'items', 'description', 'quoted_by'],
      dbIntFields:['quote_ref', 'quantity', 'amount', 'discount', 'total'],
      dbObjFields:['inquiry', 'booking']
    }
  },
  
  methods:{
    setDbData(){
      let entity = this.quote;
      this.getDbData(entity, this);
      
      //passing this (instance) as a parameter
      
      
    }
  }
  
});
```

Passing the instance ("this") to the methods as vm, it works as expected.

I am not sure if this is the best way to do it. But then it surely is not inheritance.
How to use inheritance to achieve what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You should use Mixins to add common functionality to multiple (or all of your) components: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html

This will let you add the same functions to any or all of your components, so you can automatically add `this.foobar()` to your components.

If you want to add functionality to all of your components without polluting your component namespace, you can use a custom plugin: https://vuejs.org/guide/plugins.html

This will let you add a service to all of your components so you can use it everywhere like `this.$service.foobar()`.

If you want to work with CRUD functionality, you should create a resource using `VueResource`: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-resource/blob/master/docs/resource.md

This will let you easily create/delete/edit resources using `FoobarService.create({foo: 'bar'})` or `FoobarService.delete({id: 1})`

Edit: to create a plugin, it will look something like this:

```
var MyPlugin = {};

MyPlugin.install = function (Vue, options) {

  var service = {
    foo: function(bar) {
      //do something
    }
  }

  Vue.prototype.$service = service;
}

Vue.use(MyPlugin); //this runs the install function

//Then when you have any Vue instance
this.$service.foo(bar);
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little on how can I approach to write a plugin for my requirement? I cannot figure out from the information on the plugin link. The example shown provides three options global methods, directives and instance method. I am unable to figure out where should I put my methods in the plugin definition so that I can then use it in components as `this.$service.method()`. Can you point me to some resource where I can find detailed instructions or a "Hello World" kind of example on how to write a plugin? Please

Comment: Thank you very much @Jeff for taking interest and sparing time to help me and providing the plugin code. Thanks again.

Comment: I tried the mixin as well as the plugin approach. Using the mixin approach, I have to write import statement in each of the component (file) to use the mixin in the component and it allows using `this` in mixin methods which will refer to the calling component which I need. While when using the plugin approach, I don't have to import the plugin in each component (file), but it does not allow use of `this` in the methods to refer the calling component. So I have to pass the component instance reference `vm=this` and then pass `vm as parameter to methods of plugin`.

Comment: How can I make `this` within a plugin method refer to the instance of the calling component instead of plugin itself? Is it possible? Sorry to bother you again. Can you please help me here?

Comment: Can you please have a look at my related question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38178447/how-to-encapsulate-the-common-functionality-in-a-vuejs-project

Comment: Well.. this is a common mistake to misunderstand "common functionality" with abstract classes - which is a concept from object-oriented programming.

The relation being expressed with composition is "has a <component>". This is good for 80% of the cases. However if we have a set of controls that are the same just differ in small parts then it may be an "is a <component>" relation which is expressed with inheritance.

A good example is a base dialog with imperative API (like a "showModal()" method) and dialogs that are inherited from that base dialog component.

Comment: The suggested edit queue is full, but here's the new link to the [mixin documentation guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html)